# How to make Slide in out Animation flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

Hello i want to make animation like slide in out for multiple widgets with some delay. I used https://github.com/Norbert515/flutter_sequence_animation package but for some reason last animatable showing first.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sequence_animation/flutter_sequence_animation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;
  late SequenceAnimation sequenceAnimation;
  void initAnimation() {
    double screenSize = 500; // MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5500));
    sequenceAnimation = SequenceAnimationBuilder()
        .addAnimatable(
          animatable: Tween<double>(begin: -100, end: 200),
          tag: 'source',
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          from: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
          to: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        )
        .addAnimatable(
          animatable: Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: screenSize),
          tag: 'source',
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          from: Duration(milliseconds: 1250),
          to: Duration(milliseconds: 2250),
        )
        .addAnimatable(
          animatable: Tween<double>(begin: -100, end: screenSize),
          from: Duration(milliseconds: 2250),
          to: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          tag: 'plane',
        )
        .addAnimatable(
          animatable: Tween<double>(begin: -200, end: 200),
          tag: 'test',
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          from: Duration(milliseconds: 3500),
          to: Duration(milliseconds: 4500), 
        )
        .addAnimatableAfterLastOneWithTag(
          animatable: Tween<double>(begin: 200, end: screenSize),
          tag: 'test',
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          lastTag: 'test', 
        )
        .animate(controller);

    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAnimation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    sequenceAnimation["source"].value,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    sequenceAnimation["test"].value,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text('Tesrt'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: controller,
            builder: (context, child) => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                    sequenceAnimation["plane"].value,
                    0.0,
                    0.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what i want to do ;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_qv3HskOLY

If anyone can help I will be very grateful.

Comment: The youtube video is not available

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede Sorry my fault, it should available now.

Comment: Have you found a solution?